# Tails 1.3.2 takes an inordinately long time to start on Alienware 14.

Tags: tails

I have verified the Download.  Same ISO of Tails 1.3.2 starts far faster on a 2009 Mac Book Pro.  A previous version of Tails also took much longer to boot, but eventually it would start, and probably would this time.   I have the Ethernet cable from the router Plugged in, worked well for the Mac and in the Windows of the Alienware.  I am starting in Tails Option Safe mode.  While yes, it adds more time, I turned off the fast boot in the BIOS, thinking that while it would do a memory check, Tails is not the Windows 8.1 PRO.   I turned off the secure boot and UEFI, and set it to use Legacy Boot.  After 15 minutes booting on Alienware,  I get past where Tails asks its long list, do i want to log in, Do I want to use a bridge.   I choose none of those. I would guess it takes over thirty minutes to boot Tails in a far faster Alienware than Mac Book Pro.  Absurdly long.   I am guessing some Alienware hardware is giving Tails some difficulty.   How can I get a txt list of what is happening during the boot, and see what it hardware it does not like.  Or what might I try?

Comment: Thanks for Answering.   The drive is fairly new, and seems to work pretty well with playing movies.   I suspect that I should look at a file which has all the things which are occurring at boot.  I feel that booting with a USB is essentially not very secure.  However, I might give it an experiment..

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F1 will show the Verbose boot. CTRL+ALT+F7 will get you back to the "normal" boot screen. Failsafe mode shows way more info with F1 than normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to your optical drive. If you are booting from a DVD then that might be the limiting factor. You may want to try [using a USB stick](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/index.de.html), which should be way faster than a spinning disk.

A specific reason could be that the laser inside your Mac Book is better/less dusty or that the CD you used has better compatibility with it.